# How to disable focus on textbox on load in a view in WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have a TextBox in WinRT which got the focus (Pointer focus) on load in a view in WinRT. I want to disable this and change the focus to unfocused at load. When I am in constructor of the view, the TextBox is **Unfocused**, but when I reach the event Loaded, the TextBox got, I don't know why, automatically, the focus at **Pointer**.

No instruction are done to put the focus on this control. I don't understand why it got the focus.

I try to change TabIndex, no success, the control got the focus again. When I try to put manually the focus on unfocused, I have an exception: "**Value does not fall within the expected range.**". I don't  understand why I have this exception. I have only one control with the name that I gave to him.

Thank's for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1:
You can set the textbox TabStop property to false.

Solution 2:
Set another controls TabIndex to a lower value than the TabIndex value of the texbox (the control you wish to recieve focus on startup).